# WiFi extender on network requiring Web login

Tags: wifi

I am looking to use a wifi extender at our hotel on holiday. Issue is that the hotel wifi most likely will require a Web login on the device.

Do WiFi extenders exist that allow you to do a Web login on the extender and then allow me to connect the two phones and laptop to the extender?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need a wi-fi extender if you're going to be at a hotel anyways?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no extender which will permit you to do the login. If the WiFi mode is bridge the extender will be transparent and You will have no problem with web authentication (per device - laptop, tablet, smartphone).

Moreover the hotel policies are usually "One device per account (user/password)"

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're saying with this answer. First you said no, then yes (assuming bridge mode.) Shouldn't it just be the latter?

Comment: @JMY1000, I have no info about extender which can login internally. You should login via end device. This is full answer